# mysql Creating a temporary table not working...undeclared variable error...whats wrong with my code?

Tags: sql, mysql

When I run the code below inside phpmyadmin I get an error "Undefined Variable tmpportfolio"

what is the problem?

SQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpportfolio (p_name VARCHAR(255),portfolio_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL);

SELECT p_name, portfolio_id INTO tmpportfolio
    FROM portfolio
    WHERE parent_portfolio_id IS NULL
    AND portfolio_id NOT IN
        (
           SELECT x.parent_portfolio_id
           FROM portfolio x
           WHERE x.parent_portfolio_id IS NOT NULL
        )
    AND account_id = 1

SELECT * FROM tmpportfolio;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join first two SQL statement in one [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) statment:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpportfolio SELECT p_name, portfolio_id FROM portfolio
    WHERE parent_portfolio_id IS NULL
    AND portfolio_id NOT IN
        (
           SELECT x.parent_portfolio_id
           FROM portfolio x
           WHERE x.parent_portfolio_id IS NOT NULL
        )
    AND account_id = 1

SELECT * FROM tmpportfolio;
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT field INTO variable` loads the value of the field into a variable. This is why it's complaining about the variable not being defined.

What you need to do is use an `INSERT INTO table (colummn) SELECT field` statement instead. For instance:

```
INSERT INTO tmpportfolio (p_name, portfolio_id) 
SELECT p_name, portfolio_id 
FROM portfolio
WHERE parent_portfolio_id IS NULL
AND portfolio_id NOT IN
    (
       SELECT x.parent_portfolio_id
       FROM portfolio x
       WHERE x.parent_portfolio_id IS NOT NULL
    )
AND account_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `INTO` to insert records into a table in MySql (in SQL Server, you *do* use `INTO` that way). In MySql, `INTO` is used to put a value into a variable.

By doing the `SELECT fields INTO tmpportfolio` statement, MySql thinks that `tmpportfolio` is now a variable and it cannot find the variable in the `SELECT * ..`. The fix is to change the insert-records sql to something like:

`INSERT INTO tmpportfolio(p_name,portfolio_id) SELECT ....;`

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for mysql sepcifically but usually once you have created a table you insert into it it not use selct into which creates the table (and which can't since the table already exists.)

Answer (score 0):

The confusion seems to arise from W3Schools [explaining](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) how to do "select into table" without mentioning it's specific to some (non-Mysql) implementations. [A page on dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) specifically denies this possibility on Mysql, by saying:

> MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing.